# Gradle build error when importing latest Volley Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-volley

I am having error message...

```
Error:Cause: failed to find target with hash string 'android-22' in: /Users/Dominic/Library/Android/sdk
```

...when I update the gradle files to become dependent on Volley. I downloaded SDK 22.0.1 and successfully imported Volley. I even verified the file path on both the gradle and the SDK manager were the same, and I opened my libraries folder and found in build-tools file 22.0.1.

Can someone please help me figure out why SDK won't compile Volley because it can't find the build-tools version 22.0.1 even though it is right where it is supposed to be?

I am working on a Macintosh.

Comment: Can u post your build.Gradle?

Comment: check if your sdk folder contains android-22 folder. Else download SDK platform and system images.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with gradle build. I had to download Android 5.1.1 API 22 for the gradle to build properly.